# System.NullReferenceException Windows Phone 8

Tags: windows-phone-8, nullreferenceexception

I am experiencing a strange issue, since normally this works like a charm on Windows Phone 7. I just upgraded the project to Windows Phone 8 for getting the XAP file, it crashes.

This is the part of the code which "fails":

```
/// Holds the push channel that is created or found.
HttpNotificationChannel pushChannel;

// The name of our push channel.
string channelName = "ToastSampleChannel";

InitializeComponent();

// Try to find the push channel.
pushChannel = HttpNotificationChannel.Find(channelName);

// If the channel was not found, then create a new connection to the push service.
if (pushChannel == null)
{
   pushChannel = new HttpNotificationChannel(channelName);

   // Register for all the events before attempting to open the channel.
   pushChannel.ChannelUriUpdated += new EventHandler<NotificationChannelUriEventArgs>(PushChannel_ChannelUriUpdated);
   pushChannel.ErrorOccurred += new EventHandler<NotificationChannelErrorEventArgs>(PushChannel_ErrorOccurred);

   // Register for this notification only if you need to receive the notifications while your application is running.
   //pushChannel.ShellToastNotificationReceived += new EventHandler<NotificationEventArgs>(PushChannel_ShellToastNotificationReceived);

   pushChannel.Open();

   // Bind this new channel for toast events.
   pushChannel.BindToShellToast();

}
else
{
   // The channel was already open, so just register for all the events.
   pushChannel.ChannelUriUpdated += new EventHandler<NotificationChannelUriEventArgs>(PushChannel_ChannelUriUpdated);
   pushChannel.ErrorOccurred += new EventHandler<NotificationChannelErrorEventArgs>(PushChannel_ErrorOccurred);

  // Register for this notification only if you need to receive the notifications while your application is running.
  //pushChannel.ShellToastNotificationReceived += new EventHandler<NotificationEventArgs>(PushChannel_ShellToastNotificationReceived);

  // Display the URI for testing purposes. Normally, the URI would be passed back to your web service at this point.
  System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(pushChannel.ChannelUri.ToString());
  // MessageBox.Show(String.Format("Channel Uri is {0}", pushChannel.ChannelUri.ToString()));

}
string token = pushChannel.ChannelUri.ToString();

//System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("token");
//System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(token);
//int active = 1;
object uniqueID;
string deviceID;

if (Microsoft.Phone.Info.DeviceExtendedProperties.TryGetValue("DeviceUniqueId", out uniqueID) == true)
{
    WB1.Navigated += WB1_Navigated;
    //getting udid
    byte[] bID = (byte[])uniqueID;
    deviceID = Convert.ToBase64String(bID);   // There you go
}
```

When it crash, the next line in being execute would be `WB1.Navigated += WB1_Navigated;`

So I think the error is in the previous if-condition, but I am not able to see what is wrong because before upgrading the target in project properties, it worked fine.

Any idea?

I add WB1_Navigated and other related methods:

```
void WB1_Navigated(object sender, System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    visitedUrls.Push(e.Uri);
}

private void WebBrowser_OnLoadCompleted(object sender,     System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    this.CoverImage.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
}

protected override void OnBackKeyPress(System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e)
{
   if (visitedUrls.Count > 1)
   {
       visitedUrls.Pop();
       WB1.Navigate(visitedUrls.Pop());
       e.Cancel = true;
   }
}
```

As petition, I show my xml code:

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage 
x:Class="WindowsPush.MainPage"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:phone="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
xmlns:shell="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Shell;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
mc:Ignorable="d" FontFamily="{StaticResource PhoneFontFamilyNormal}"
FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeNormal}"
Foreground="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}"
SupportedOrientations="Portrait" Orientation="Portrait"
shell:SystemTray.IsVisible="True" d:DesignHeight="768" d:DesignWidth="480">

<!--LayoutRoot is the root grid where all page content is placed-->
<!--Sample code showing usage of ApplicationBar-->
<!--<phone:PhoneApplicationPage.ApplicationBar>
    <shell:ApplicationBar IsVisible="True" IsMenuEnabled="True">
        <shell:ApplicationBarIconButton IconUri="/Images/appbar_button1.png" Text="Button 1"/>
        <shell:ApplicationBarIconButton IconUri="/Images/appbar_button2.png" Text="Button 2"/>
        <shell:ApplicationBar.MenuItems>
            <shell:ApplicationBarMenuItem Text="MenuItem 1"/>
            <shell:ApplicationBarMenuItem Text="MenuItem 2"/>
        </shell:ApplicationBar.MenuItems>
    </shell:ApplicationBar>
</phone:PhoneApplicationPage.ApplicationBar>-->
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="Transparent">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <phone:WebBrowser Name="WB1" LoadCompleted="WebBrowser_OnLoadCompleted"/>
    <Image x:Name="CoverImage" Width="Auto" Height="Auto" Source="\SplashScreenImage.jpg"></Image>
</Grid>


</phone:PhoneApplicationPage>
```

Comment: if WB1 is not null I assume uniqueID is null

Comment: what is your WB1? and where is your WB1_Navigated?

Comment: WB1 is a webbrowser. I added previous part of the mainPage function

Comment: This is WB1 <phone:WebBrowser Name="WB1" LoadCompleted="WebBrowser_OnLoadCompleted"/>

Comment: Yes, it fails in WB1.Navigated. How should I declare it? It was working... So I don't know hot to handle now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are getting (probably) your Exception in line:

```
string token = pushChannel.ChannelUri.ToString();
```

You get your ChanelUri after some time, and before you get it it's null. Move your token to PushChannel_ChannelUriUpdated:

```
private void PushChannel_ChannelUriUpdated(object sender, NotificationChannelUriEventArgs e)
{
    string token = pushChannel.ChannelUri.ToString();
}
```

**EDIT** - source information
According to [this blog](http://blogs.windows.com/windows_phone/b/wpdev/archive/2010/05/06/using-push-notification-from-your-windows-phone-application.aspx):
`The Open channel (a few lines of code later) is an asynchronous operation (therefore the need to attach an event handler that gets triggered once the open operation completes). If it is successful, the ChannelUriUpdate event is raised, if it fails, most probably HttpNotificationChannel will raise an ExceptionOccurred event.`

Comment: Debugging it, I see that token is printen and I can read it. But WB1 is null and cannot call the functions. So my problem I think is related to WB1 but I don't know how to fix it

Comment: @Biribu Can you show you xaml code? With WB1? I created sample code and it's working except the thing I've metioned above. Do you perform anything with WB1 before InitializeComponent?

Comment: @Biribu Have you enables Capabilites: ID_CAP_IDENTITY_DEVICE, ID_CAP_PUSH_NOTIFICATION, ID_CAP_WEBBROWSERCOMPONENT?

Comment: Yes, all of them enabled. The strange part for me is that the problem is just with windows phone 8 target. If I use a windows phone 7 target as project target, it works fine.

Comment: @Biribu and if oyou comment out line WB1.Navigated... it works? Strange, my sample code runs without issue.

Comment: It crash at the next line I use WB1, which is  WB1.IsScriptEnabled = true; 2 o3 lines after that

Comment: @Biribu Where is your Wb1.IsScritEnables? - I can't see it in the code you provided. So it crashes getting UID then?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/46017/discussion-between-biribu-and-romasz)

Comment: Thanks man, you solved my problem by chat. I wish I could give you more points